# How to horizontally align headers and decimal centered cells

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I use this code to produce a table and to align the column with the dot of the numerical values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{3} D{.}{.}{3}}
\firsthline
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header 2} \\
\hline
\hline
Length & 1.489 & 2.569 \\
Width & 5 & 2.4\\
\lasthline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: The obtained table.]

Two requests for this table:

I would like to have the headers properly centered with the numerical values.

How can I specify the width of the columns produced with the `D` function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a job for `siunitx`. This package makes available `S` columns with *many* more features than those provided by `dcolumn`. For instance, your case can be treated with

```
S[table-format=1.3]
```

where `1.3` specifies one digit for the integral part and three for the decimal part. You can use exponential (also known as scientific) notation with proper alignment and change easily many aspects of data typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]} }
\toprule
 & {Header 1} & {Header 2} \\
\midrule
Length & 1.489 & 2.569 \\
Width & 5 & 2.4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've added also the rules as drawn by `booktabs`

[image]

Comment: That seems to do the job for the centering part, but what about the definition of the width? Is it possible to define the desired width of a S column?

Comment: @LudovicC. I don't get it.

Comment: Let say I would like to have the column header 1 with a width of 10 cm (even though that might not be aesthetic), can I do that?

Comment: @LudovicC. `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox[10cm]{Header 1}}`

Comment: Nice. When I compile with ``pdflatex``, ``siunitx`` forces several "passes", while Gonzalo's ``dcolumn`` solution doesn't. So unless I absolutely need ``siunitx`` I tend to go for ``dcolumn``. Is this something others have noticed? Perhaps I'm experiencing interference with some other package.

Answer (score 8):

One place before the decimal separator, three after it, so use `D{1.3}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l D{.}{.}{1.3} D{.}{.}{1.3}}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Header 2} \\
\midrule
Length & 1.489 & 2.569 \\
Width & 5 & 2.4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to look a few times for the differences.

Comment: Ok for the centering. Do you know how to specify the with of a D column?